# Understanding the structure

Tags: c#

Assume the following code in C#.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Age{ get; set; }
    public int Dob{ get; set; }
}
```

With the above code I can access the properties of `Class1` and `Class2` with out an issue. However, If I do something like.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public class Class2
    {
        public int Age{ get; set; }
        public int Dob{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

I wont be able to access the properties of `Class2` but I don't get any errors compile time. Can someone explain to me why that is? I'm still in the learning process of C# so if this is something basic then I do apologise.

**Further Info**

If I want to get a value from DB I use the following code.

```
public static int Age()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {

        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        Class2 info = new Class2();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Age FROM Users WHERE UserName=@userName"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", userName);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    info.Age= reader.GetInt32(0);
                }
            }
        }
        return info.Age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685629/class-declared-inside-of-another-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you show an example of how you are trying to "access the properties of `Class2`? Actually, it should be possible.

Comment: "I wont be able to access the properties of Class2" - seems to be completely false... `Class1.Class2` should be perfectly visible - please show code that demonstrates "not able to access" part.

Comment: `var c2 = new Class1.Class2() { Age = 24 };`

Comment: @Downvoter care to say why?

Comment: You're added code, with the sql query, should work fine if that the method is inside of Class1

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: ... and if it's not, your (the OP's) problem is *not* "accessing the properties of `Class2`" (as implied by your question), but instantiating `Class2` in the statement `Class2 info = new Class2();`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The method is in a different class to Class1

Comment: @Code given that code, you don't even need a `Class2`, just have an `int`.

Comment: Code, You still have not explained what "I wont be able to access the properties of Class2 but I don't get any errors compile time." means and shown sample - you posted code, but it is unclear whether it shows "not able to access" or what. Show and comment code which you think should not work and where do you expect compile time errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Class2` become a nested class. You can create it like this:

```
Class1.Class2 class2 = new Class1.Class2();
```

then you can use his property like all normal instances:

```
class2.Age = 0;
class2.Dob = 0;
```

But i think that waht you are trying to achieve is to have a property to the type of your `Class2`:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Class2 Info { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Age{ get; set; }
    public int Dob{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access his parameter:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
class1.Info = new Class2();

class1.Info.Age = 0;
class1.Info.Dob= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Class1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public class Class2
    {
        public int Age{ get; set; }
        public int Dob{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Class2` is an `internal` class declaration within `Class1` you have not declared an instance of `Class2` and therefore have no way of getting these fields. To meet what you want todo:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Class2 Instance {get; set;}

    public class Class2
    {
        public int Age{ get; set; }
        public int Dob{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then access with `myClass1.Instance.Age`